# Transferring an app with an attached database to another Heroku account

Tags: heroku

I made an application in Heroku with a PostgreSQL addon and I want to transfer them to another account.

1. I didn't find any "transfer to another account" option for the PostgreSQL addon. Does it move automatically with the app? Should I create another database in the destination account and link it to the app after transferring it?
2. Will the repository location be affected? Do the collaborators have to re-clone the repository?
3. How long will the transfer process take? While it is transferring, can we still view the app / push code to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you transfer a Heroku app its add-ons should come with it. Transfers take place very quickly once the receiver has accepted the transfer, and the transfer process shouldn't affect the running app.

The Heroku Git URL will change, but [you shouldn't be using this as your main code repository](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app):

> Heroku provides the git service primarily for deployment, and the ability to clone from it is offered as a convenience. We strongly recommend you store your code in another git repository such as [GitHub](https://github.com/) and treat that as canonical.

Nobody should be cloning from that URL. Either way, you'll have to update your Heroku remote's URL, e.g. using [`git remote --set-url`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#git-remote-emset-urlem).